# Lawvere's Conceptual Mathematics: What is a product?

Tags: category-theory, arithmetic

In the introduction to *Conceptual Mathematics*, Lawvere and Schanuel present the concept of multiplying objects with the following diagrams:

[image]

Here a meal is made up of two choices: $\text{MEAL}=\text{1st COURSE} \times \text{2nd COURSE}$, and space is made up of a point on a plane and a point line: $\text{SPACE}=\text{POINT}\times\text{LINE}$. They emphasize that "three 'objects' and two 'maps' or processes is the right picture of multiplication of objects." Two objects are combining to form a third; or, one object is being decomposed into two.

An example, $6=3\times2$, from basic arithmetic is given:

[image]

My question is this: how does viewing multiplication through this lens distinguish it from addition?

[image]

**Attempted Answer**: Multiplication, in an abstract sense, is about different ways of combining two objects. We need two pieces of information: $\text{1st COURSE}$ and $\text{2nd COURSE}$ to determine a specific choice of $\text{MEALS}$. Likewise, we need two pieces of information: point on $\text{PLANE}$ ($2\text{D}$) and point on $\text{LINE}$ ($1\text{D}$) to determine a point in $\text{SPACE}$ ($3\text{D}$). Moreover, how multiplication combines two objects to form a third seems intimately related to the Cartesian product from set theory. Indeed, the  $\text{MEALS}$ and $\text{SPACE}$ examples are the Cartesian product.

The example from arithmetic seems more nuanced...every dot in the $6$-rectangle can be associated with one of the $2$-dots and one of the $3$-dots. However, the number $6$ is not a set of ordered pairs; rather, it is the *cardinality* of the set of six ordered pairs.

Perhaps the product of any two objects $A$ and $B$ is the cartesian product $A\times B$, possibly followed by an additional operation? In the case of $3\times 2$, arithmetic multiplication is not the the Cartesian product but the cardinality of the Cartesian product. The dot product of two vectors is a similar example: the coordinates in each pair generated by taking the cartesian product are multiplied together (different coordinates are multiplied by 0) and the result summed to a scalar.

I want to pinpoint exactly why certain operations on two objects are called products. Is it a relationship to the cartesian product? Something else?

Comment: What you wrote as "My question" seems easily answered by pointing out that your arrow picture of $5=3+2$ looks almost nothing like the arrow picture of $6 = 3 \times 2$.

Comment: On the other hand your final question, regarding relations amongst various uses of "product", seems to be the actual question, is that right?

Comment: @LeeMosher Essentially, yes. The final question is the actual one.  Although the arrow picture of $5=3+2$ looks different than the arrow picture of $6=3\times 2$, it looks similar to the $\text{SPACE}=\text{LINE}\times\text{PLANE}$.

Comment: Well, one thing I would suggest is to focus on the differences rather than the similarities. It's pretty easy to connect three concepts in a specious pattern like that, i.e. a pattern without any meaning behind it. As it stands, it's rather hard to understand your question as it is currently written.

Comment: @LeeMosher My question evolved from the book's statement "three 'objects' and two 'maps' or processes is the right picture of multiplication of objects." I interpreted this as suggesting that, somehow, diagrams such as the first two posted in the question provide insight into what multiplication really "is".

Comment: The thing that distinguishes a *product* from two generic arrows with the same domain is *universality*. See Article IV, and in particular section 4, which has a more formal definition of product.

Comment: Addition is the coproduct, where you form the disjoint union of the dots. The arrows go the opposite way too.